# Strange issue with padding in CSS blockquote styling

Tags: css, styling

I am using the following code to style blockquotes on my site:

```
blockquote {
border-left: 7px solid #b83131;
background: #ebebeb;
margin: 1.5em 25px;
padding: 1px 10px;
quotes:"\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
}
```

The line that begins with `padding:` controls the padding on the top and bottom of the block quote. For some reason, it doesn't work as it should. Instead of padding by only `1px`, it is always way more than that. It's as if, no matter what I set as the padding, it is always at least a few pixels high.

For example, with the padding set as you see in the code above, this is the result:

[image: blockquote]

As you can see, the padding on the top and bottom is way more than `1px`. Why is that? I want the padding to be a true `1px`, but it seems that no matter how I alter the code, it's either no padding at all, or way more than `1px`.

Any help here?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Please post the HTML code as well or prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Do you have any other elements wrapping the text in the `blockquote`, Like `<p>`s?

Comment: The issue is that I am hosting the site on Squarespace, so I am not sure. Eh. This sucks. I realize now that I don't have nearly enough info on this. I cannot seem to reproduce it (yet) on jsfiddle.

Comment: Say there is a `<p>` tag around block quotes — is there any CSS I can use to tell it to ignore that? I do not have access to the Squarespace internals...

Comment: `p` around `blockquote` won't cause this problem, I guess. But if you have a `p` inside the `blockquote`, then this might be the problem, `p` have `margin` and maybe for some reason they are not collapsing.

Comment: Can you use `JavaScript`? I think `jQuery` can solve this problem easily.

Comment: Try setting `padding: 0 10px`. If this works, its the collapse problem then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XBcEa/1/), you will see that with only the code you posted, one cannot reproduce the problem.

I for myself believe that there is a `<p>` tag inside your `blockquote`.
Just remove it by setting its margin to 0.

```
p {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: This does seem to be the problem, but how can I target only blockquotes?

Comment: If your question is how to target `p`'s that are in `blockquotes`, then this should do the job: `blockquote p {
    margin: 0px;
}`. But I'm sure you already knew that.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, but I still want there to be a line break between paragraphs within a block quote. Removing the margin completely removes any break between paragraphs. Crap. Am I just SOL here?

Comment: I don't think you're out of luck. Take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/XBcEa/4/  By using `first-child` and `last-child` you can address the margin between the first `p` and `blockquote` and the last `p` and `blockquotes`.

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the line height of the text within the blockquote.  It might be that the 1px top and bottom padding is enough to for the text to kick down to the next full line making it looks like it's over padded.

Comment: Oh.  Well that's all I got.  Might be worth it to inspect in one of the browsers developer tools and play with the CSS rules there until you hit on something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the a similar problem:  I was trying to minimize the space above the block quotation, so I set

```
BLOCKQUOTE  {margin-top: 0}
```

This seemed to work sometimes, but not always.

Here's what I discovered:  When it didn't work, there was an unclosed paragraph <P> tag somewhere above the quotation.  The opening <BLOCKQUOTE> tag effectively closes that paragraph, so the unwanted whitespace was coming, not from the top margin of the quotation, but from the bottom margin of the paragraph above it.  This fixed it:

```
BLOCKQUOTE  {margin-top: 0}
P   {margin-bottom: 0}
```

Of course, if you don't want *every* paragraph to have zero bottom margin, you can define a special class.